# I need to send simple rtp static packet over udp

Tags: rtp

I'm looking for sample rtp packet with silence voice that i just can send over udp and i have to keep sending that static packet with the hard code values.
I will use this for some stress testing of media server.
Please help me with simple code packet buffer so i just can send over UDP without any changes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An RtpPacket with PayloadType set to 13 identifies a ConformNoise packet and does not require a payload.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3389

You may additionally use the SDP to determine the codec and produce a sample which corresponds to the duration of silence you need.